# Failed to load API definition in Swagger-UI using open-api 3

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

In a spring boot 3.1.2 project, I am trying to access the v3/api-docs but it throws an error 500 mentioning 'Failed to load API definition'. Also getting this error while I am trying to access the endpoint

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at io.swagger.v3.core.jackson.SwaggerAnnotationIntrospector.hasRequiredMarker(SwaggerAnnotationIntrospector.java:29)
at org.springdoc.core.configuration.SpringDocRequiredModule$RespectSchemaRequiredAnnotationIntrospector.hasRequiredMarker(SpringDocRequiredModule.java:60)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.hasRequiredMarker(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:319)

What could be the reason for this? The project has necessary maven dependencies

The project uses open-api code generator and has necessary maven dependencies